# EWS : Convert email adress from X500 to smtp address

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm extracting emails using the EWS API, sometimes, `Sender.Address` property returns somthing like this :

```
/O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=USERXXXXXXX
```

I think it's X500 email format, I tried :

```
var resolutions = service.ResolveName(email.Sender.Address);
```

but, the collection is empty ! am I missing anything ?

I used EWSEditor, and when I tried to use ResolveName, I got :

```
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:ResolveNamesResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:ResolveNamesResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
            <m:MessageText>Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé.</m:MessageText>
            <m:ResponseCode>ErrorNameResolutionNoResults</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          </m:ResolveNamesResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:ResolveNamesResponse>
    </s:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you resolve the address in outlook ? eg past into a new message and do a ctrl-K if that address can't be resolved to an Entry in the Global Address List then that's the result you would get. That may indicate that the address that refers to the X500 address has been deleted or a migration was done and no ProxyAddress was added.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I'll try this, but If the address hs been deleted ? is there a way to get the email address ?

Comment: It depends it maybe located in another property eg for the sender address the SMTP address maybe in PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS property. The best thing to do is use a Mapi editor like OutlookSpy or MFCMapi to look at the object. For recipient addresses generally the SMTPAddress is held in PR_SMTP_Address in the recipients collection but that property isn't directly accessible with EWS so you need to use MAPI to extract that.

Answer (score 1):

The Email X500 format must be converted to SMTP to be readable as a standard email format. I tried Resolve Names but my application handles more than 1000 entries. Hence I used `LoadPropertiesForItems` to extract email addresses.

```
//Define a property set
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ContactSchema.EmailAddress1);

//get all contact items
var findContact = service.FindItems(new FolderId("AXXX"), view);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findContact, view.PropertySet);

foreach (Contact item in findContact.Items)
{
    EmailAddress emAdd;
    var emailVal = item.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out emAdd);
    //do your functionality
}
```

I could extract the email addresses.